# Is there an R function to do a survival analysis with right censoring + nested + crossed factors

Tags: r, mixed-model, survival, random-effects-model

I have this dataset to model, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I want to model the **surviving probability** of different populations of two **species** depending on a **treatment** applied.

Populations should be **nested within species**, as they belong to either species 1 or species 2. And, as I have replicated measures for each population x treatment combination, I need to include this as a random effect as well.

What R function can I use to do that? Is there one?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look perhaps in http://www.springer.com/mathematics/probability/book/978-0-387-72834-6 (available on libgen) - that discusses survival models with random factors, and gives examples in R in the suppl material

Answer (score 0):

I will say "no". There is nothing that does that unless you want to restrict yourself to a Cox model.